# ANTLR v3 Parsing domain specific language

Tags: antlr3, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a scripting language of the form:
`<keyword> = <text>,`

Where `<text>` can contain keywords and sometimes the `<text>` can contain instructions depending on what `<keyword>` is used.

I am trying to handle the `<text>` based on what `<keyword>` is used.

```
/* lang.g */
grammar lang;

/* parser rules */
script     : assignment+ ;

assignment : keyword VALUE ;

/* cannot do the following (but I would like to)

assignment : command | command_b | display ;
command    : COMMAND '=' /* parser rules for command */ ',' ;
command_b  : COMMAND_B '=' /* parser rules for command_b */ ',' ;
display    : DISPLAY '=' ~(',')+ ',' ;
*/

/* lexer rules */
VALUE      : '='! ~(',')+ ','!

COMMAND    : 'command' ;
COMMAND_B  : 'command_b' ;
DISPLAY    : 'display' ;

WS         : (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;} ;
```

Example input file:

```
command = goto->step_b,
display = this is some plain text. command keyword used,
command_b = read_file:"readme.txt",
```

I want to be able to handle `command`, `command_b` and `display` rules differently using ANTLR to parse everything without using a target language to assist.  Using the above *.g file; the first line have `command` and `goto->step_b` as tokens.  `goto->step_b` needs to be parsed further, it would be nice to have ANTLR do all that work rather than the target language.

If there isn't a way to do this directly, I thought I would accomplish this in two stages.

1. Use *.g file above to parse input file
2. Cull everything but `command` and `command_b` nodes; feed those nodes into another parser using a grammar defined for `command` and `command_b` syntax only.

Is there a way to parse the script using a single grammar such that I can handle `command`/`command_b` rules differently than any other rule? Or will I have to process the script file in multiple stages?

Thanks for any help.

Josh

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my answer here:

[antlr identifier name same as pre-defined function name cause MismatchedTokenException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883587/antlr-identifier-name-same-as-pre-defined-function-name-cause-mismatchedtokenexc/15031790#15031790)

You can use disambiguating semantic predicates to keep these rules out of your grammar:

```
COMMAND    : 'command' ;
COMMAND_B  : 'command_b' ;
DISPLAY    : 'display' ;
```

And instead you will write rules like:

```
functions_stats 
  :   {input.LT(1).getText().equals("command")}? '=' /* parser rules for command */ ',' ;  
  ;
```

The action in the semantic predicate is language specific, so may differ based on your target language.  It works for Java and probably a number of others as well.