# antlr identifier name same as pre-defined function name cause MismatchedTokenException

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

I have defined a ANTLR grammer:

```
grammar test5;

stats_statement
:   
    STATS IDENT ASSIGN_SYM functions_stats

;

functions_stats 

:   COUNT LPAREN IDENT RPAREN   
;

STATS
:   'STATS'
;   

COUNT
:   'count'
;   

IDENT
:   (LETTER | '_') (LETTER | DIGIT | '_')*
;   

ASSIGN_SYM
: ':='
;

COMMA_SYM
: ','
;

SEMI_SYM
: ';'
;

LPAREN 
: '(' ;

RPAREN 
: ')' ;

fragment 
LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ;

fragment 
DIGIT : '0'..'9';
```

which has one build-in function "count". But if I use the following test string:

```
STATS count:=count(col1)
```

the parser will return an error saying:

```
mismatched input 'count' expecting IDENT
```

any clue and/or hints on how to fix this problem?

Thanks
Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `ident` rule that matched both `IDENT` and `COUNT` and use that rule in your parser rules (instead of using `IDENT`):

```
stats_statement
 : STATS ident ASSIGN_SYM functions_stats
 ;

functions_stats 
 :   COUNT LPAREN ident RPAREN   
 ;

ident
 : COUNT
 | IDENT
 ;
```

Comment: It works. But if I have lots of pre-defined function, does it mean I need to add all those function names to the 'ident'?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need COUNT to be recognized in the lexer?  Consider defining a more general method to match functions.

```
function 
  :   fn=IDENT LPAREN IDENT (',' IDENT)* RPAREN   
  ;
```

Then you can add an action to handle your semantics, such as looking up the function name in a table and making sure it has the right number of parameters, etc.

If that doesn't fit with what you needed to do, you could instead eliminate your `COUNT` rule and rewrite your `functions_stats` rule:

```
functions_stats 
  :   {input.LT(1).getText().equals("count")}? IDENT LPAREN IDENT RPAREN   
  ;
```

the `{...}?` is a disambiguating semantic predicate (see page 295 of The Definitive ANTLR Reference by Terence Parr).  Only if it evaluates to true will this match.  ANTLR 3 has a feature called 'hoisted semantic predicates' which basically means that semantic predicate is put into the appropriate callers of `functions_stats` so that information is used to make the decisions of what to parse.

Page 296 of the book has a section called "Keywords as Variables", here is the sample code from that chapter:  http://media.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/code/predicates/keywords/Pred.g which might give you a better understanding.

The book itself is quite useful if you are doing advanced ANTLR work.  The online documentation doesn't cover this stuff well.